# Add Custom Function to Posts in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I love the Custom Post Templates plugin so much I want to build it into my themes.

The function [can be found here](http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/wordpress-single-post-templates/), but it only works for pages.  How do I get this to also work for posts?

```
add_filter('single_template', create_function('$t', 'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) { if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->term_id}.php") ) return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->term_id}.php"; } return $t;' ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the website you linked, this should work for posts and pages. Also, according to the WordPress docs (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/_single_template), the 'single_template' filter is used for both posts and pages.

Do you have a separate single.php file with the correct category ID in the name? e.g. single-2.php

If no correctly named single.php file is found, it will revert back to the standard single.php file. Is this what you're seeing?

EDIT:

If you wanted this option actually in the Wordpress Admin area, I would suggest using Post Meta to store the value of the single.php file you want to use.

You could add a custom meta box to the admin page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box then you could use some of your code from your original question to get all the available single.php template files, and drop them into a drop down list:

```
$templates = array();
foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) { 
    if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->term_id}.php") ) 
        $templates[] = TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->term_id}.php";
}
```

You would then need to add a filter similar to your original one:

```
function custom_single_template($t){
    global $post;

    if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name_of_key', true) ) {

      return TEMPLATEPATH . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name_of_key', true);

    }

    return $t;

}
add_filter('single_template', 'custom_single_template');
```

Comment: The code I've provided above works.  The problem is I want a dropdown box asking which template to use when I edit/create a post... just like there is when I create a page with this function.  The plugin has this functionality, but the function does not.

Comment: Ah, that's not exactly what you originally asked. The ability to select the page template is a default Wordpress feature. I've updated my answer with a way you could do it for posts.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure it out with this.  Thanks for trying.